# DataTrigger not working within a ListBox.ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatrigger

Let me give a brief overview of my issue.

I have a Window that has a ViewModel as a data context. This window also has 2 User Controls within it. These user controls have various xaml objects that bind to properties in the ViewModel, and I am having no problems with any other properties.

The issue I am having is that a data trigger that I have created will not fire. Below you can see the xaml for the data trigger that I have tried:

**Note:** IsBold is a property within the ViewModel that I am using for the Window. I am under the impression that user controls within a window will inherit the data context from the parent, so I don't think that is my problem.

```xml
<ScrollViewer >
        <ListBox
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Listings}"
            SelectionMode="Single"
            SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedListingItemID}"
            SelectedValuePath="ItemID"
            Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="NotTriggered" />
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsBold}" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="Triggered" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </TextBlock.Style>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

When I run this, I will get the output statement:

**BindingExpression path error: 'DataContext' property not found on 'object' ''DataRowView'**

This message leads me to believe that I need to move the data trigger to another part of the xaml so that it realizes that the property is from the ViewModel and not the ListBoxItem, but where do I move it? Or is that even the right thing to do?

I hope I was clear enough in all the necessary areas, but if I wasn't, I can certainly elaborate where needed.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you comment out the lines one by one, does the error eventually go away and on what line?  The error message doesn't appear to be related to the code that is displayed.

Comment: It's not a error per se. It displays a binding error in the output window when I run the program. If I commented out the lines, then the binding would never happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to use [relative source property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource.aspx), you can check IsBold from your window's dataContext using FindAncestor mode and AncestorType of Window, something like this:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}, Path=IsBold}" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Triggered" />
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: I had to heavily modify the code you wrote, but your link led me on the right path to fix the problem I was having. However, I now have a related but more difficult problem that probably requires another question.